# Remove "Delete" menu for BlackBerry application

Tags: blackberry

I want to remove "Delete" menu for application from home screen or download folder or wherever it is placed.

How can i achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

As I understand you would want your application to be installed so that the user CANNOT delete the application.

First, you will need to rethink if this requirement is justified. Suppose you are the end user and purchased the latest and greatest Blackberry phone for $600 and you install this application which you have found to be annoying (say this application sends SMS to some unknown number) and blast your phone bill. Ask yourself if you want to have the ability to delete this application.

Second, with this kind of feature, you will NEVER be able to host your application in Blackberry App World. Your application will be rejected outright. Consumers will not be able to install your app from App World.

Third, it is not possible to accomplish this. The following changes can be made to your application's icon

1. Change the application name of displayed
2. Change the application's Icon. This can be useful to alert the user that there is something interesting happening with the application.
3. Change the application's roll over icon.

That's it!

Nothing else if possible.